# How to find maximum form custom object of objects using java 8

Tags: java-8, mapreduce, java-stream

I have list of object (please ignore syntax I have changed names, the code compiles well)

```
List<Employees> list=Arrays.asList(new Employee(),new Employee() ........ nth new Employee());
Employee
{
 String name;
 String address;
 .
 .
 .
 String phone;
 IncomeSRC1 src1;
 IncomeSRC2 src2;
 IncomeSRC3 src3;
}
IncomeSRC1{
String details;
double amount;
.
.
.
}
IncomeSRC2{
String details;
double amount;
.
.
.
}
IncomeSRC3{
String details;
double amount;
.
.
.
}
```

I want to find max of amount in list from each Income source using Java8, can it be achieved using **single** stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do like this. first extract `income` properties for each employee as below then by using `toMap` collector with three parameters find the maximum amount for each income source.

the advantage for this way is doing it in single stream and the disadvantage is kinda hard-coding.

```
Map<String, Double> result = 
list.stream()
    .map(employee -> Arrays.asList(
          new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("src1", employee.getSrc1().getAmount()),
          new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("src2", employee.getSrc2().getAmount()),
          new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("src3", employee.getSrc3().getAmount())
     ))
   .flatMap(List::stream)
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Double::max));
```

and other way is like this:

```
List<Optional<Double>>  result =   Stream.of(
            list.stream().map(Employee::getSrc1).map(IncomeSRC1::getAmount)
                .max(Double::compareTo),
            list.stream().map(Employee::getSrc2)
                .map(IncomeSRC2::getAmount).max(Double::compareTo),
            list.stream().map(Employee::getSrc3)
                .map(IncomeSRC3::getAmount).max(Double::compareTo)
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer tested and it works for my original requirement,
anyways here is answer (names are changed it compiles successfully returns valid ans)

```
AtomicReference<Double> src1 = new AtomicReference<>();
AtomicReference<Double> src2 = new AtomicReference<>();
AtomicReference<Double> src3 = new AtomicReference<>();
        src1.set(0d);
        src2.set(0d);
        src3.set(0d);
        list.stream().forEach(
                i-> {
                    //add null checks and other business logic 
                    if( i.getIncomeSRC1().getAmount() >src1.get()) src1.set( i.getIncomeSRC1().getAmount());
                    if( i.getIncomeSRC2().getAmount() >src2.get()) src2.set( i.getIncomeSRC2().getAmount());
                    if( i.getIncomeSRC3().getAmount() >src3.get()) src3.set( i.getIncomeSRC3().getAmount());
                }
                );
```